# Webpack source map imports are not defined (firefox debugger)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox, browser, webpack

I've been trying to figure out webpack and generating source maps. While the source maps to come out, I'm not able to debug the imports. See this picture of [chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLmmr.png) and [firefox (57 dev edition) debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmgcP.png) (and just for proof that the debugger is working is [here is a website on the internet being debugged in another firefox window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s00Ya.png)).

I would prefer to use firefox, so how can I set source maps to work correctly and give me information about imported modules.

My minimal example is here:

### main.ts

```
import { write } from './utils';
import { Stack } from './stack';

const appRef: any= document.querySelector('#app');

const stack: Stack = new Stack(['alice', 'bob', 'eve']);

stack.add('charlie');

write(stack.members.toString(), appRef);
```

### stack.ts

```
export class Stack {

  private _members: string[];

  constructor(members: string[]) {
    this._members = members;
  }

  get members(): string[] {
    return this._members;
  }

  push(member: string) {
    this._members.push(member);
  }

  pop(): string | undefined {
    return this._members.pop();
  }

}
```

### utils.ts

```
export function write(text: string, domElement: any) {
  if (domElement) {
    const textNode: any = document.createTextNode(text);
    domElement.append(textNode);
  } else {
    document.write(text);
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Comment: I am legit saddened by the fact that this issue was posted over 3 years ago with no responses.  I have always had this issue... but i guess nobody else cares :(

Comment: @TravRob The issue is build tools, such as webpack, rewrite import variable names in the bundled javascript output, so for whatever reason sometimes, some browsers perhaps, the sourcemaps don't map to the variables. Unfortunate definitely, kinda just learned to live with it. One solution is to look at the `Scope` panel on the right side (under the `Call Stack`) and you might see the imports there under their compiled names